# why am I getting this error : AttributeError: 'LocalStack' object has no attribute '__ident_func__' in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create an app with flask, and I am in this step that I need to connect my database which is in my local server, to achieve this I have used the command db = SQLAlchemy(app) and imported SQLALchemy from flask-alchemy(I have provided my codes bellow in detail).when I start my flask app server I get the error AttributeError: 'LocalStack' object has no attribute '--ident_func--' pointing to the line with db = SQLAlchemy(app). Any help will be appreciated cause I really don't know what I am missing.

app.py

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Imports
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Configs
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Models
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#to include my database schema models later

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# routes
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('pages/home.html')


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

config.py

```
# Enable debug mode.
DEBUG = True

# Connect to the database
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/fyyurdb'
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>hello world</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

pip freeze (requirements.txt)

```
Babel==2.9.0
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.4
Flask==2.1.2
Flask-Moment==0.11.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
greenlet==1.1.2
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2022.1
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.36
Werkzeug==2.1.2
WTForms==3.0.1
```

error massage on terminal

```
(fyyurenv) C:\Users\Gm Kahosh\Desktop\fyyur\cd0046-SQL-and-Data-Modeling-for-the-Web>python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gm Kahosh\Desktop\fyyur\cd0046-SQL-and-Data-Modeling-for-the-Web\app.py", line 13, in <module>
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
  File "C:\Users\Gm Kahosh\Desktop\fyyur\fyyurenv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 714, in __init__
    self.session = self.create_scoped_session(session_options)
  File "C:\Users\Gm Kahosh\Desktop\fyyur\fyyurenv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 747, in create_scoped_session                                                                                                                                 on
    scopefunc = options.pop('scopefunc', _app_ctx_stack.__ident_func__)
AttributeError: 'LocalStack' object has no attribute '__ident_func__'
```

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar issue, I uninstalled it using `python -m pip uninstall flask-sqlalchemy` and installed with `python -m pip install flask-sqlalchemy` . The issue was solved.

Comment: The point of this is presumably to upgrade the package? It'd be nice to know which packages were uninstalled and reinstalled.

Answer (score 6):

The root cause of this issue is that a change to the Werkzeug package - which Flask depends on - required a change to how Flask constructs scoped sessions.  The change is documented [here](https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-sqlalchemy/commit/3565f0587519168c5ea4301f6e4bfba8c2ac4dee).  The error occurs if the Werkzeug package has its change but the Flask package does not.

Upgrading to Flask-SQLAlchemy >= 2.5.1 should solve the issue.

Comment: It doesn't resolved the issue

Comment: @Jurass what error message do you get exactly?  And what package versions have you installed?

Comment: In my case I'm using flask_mysqlpool and getting a similar error.  This tip was helpful in identifying the cause.  Pinning Werkzeug at 2.0.3 resolved the issue (for now, until flask_mysqlpool is fixed for compatibility with newer Werkzeug versions).

Comment: Thank you for clarification. It helped me ("from greenlet import getcurrent" worked)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem `"AttributeError: '_FakeStack' object has no attribute '__ident_func__'"` and I solved it by upgrading Flask-SQLAlchemy:

```
pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this problem by editing my `requirements.txt` to include the `psycopg2-binary` instead of `psycopg2` itself.

Afterwards, I re-built the docker environment (`docker-compose build`) and re-up'd the docker environment (`docker-compose up`).

In case future readers have not done so yet, I also needed to deactivate the docker environment before the above process (`docker-compose down`).

Answer (score 0):

I really should have mentioned that the source codes I had cloned from a GitHub repo so there was code pollution that affected my code files I guess despite installing all the requirements with the command `pip install -r requirement.txt`. A work around this is that I deleted all my project files and started my project independently without any starter templates from the GitHub repo. This project was just a practice exercise for me but the big question which now remains is how to clone app and successfully install all these dependency without getting the error.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. The reason you are experiencing the above issue is because you don't have **psycopg2** installed on you machine. If you are working from a virtual environment add **psycopg2**  to your **requirements.txt file** then install it via the command `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Also, confirm that the connection to your local database is working.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I tried some ways but they didn't work. When I tried below commands upgrade both Flask-SQLAlchemy and SQLAlchemy it worked.

```
pip3 install Flask-SQLAlchemy --upgrade
pip3 install SQLAlchemy --upgrade
```